Spectral Decomposition of a Matrix
The spectral decomposition of a symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is given by $A = Q \Lambda Q^T$. Where $\Lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} $ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues $ \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \dots, \lambda_n $ of $ A $. Can we say that if $c\in R(\Lambda)$ then $c\in R(A)$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}^n$?
I am working on a different problem where this result (if it is true) may come handy. Can someone help me with this? Thanks

If by $R(A)$ you mean the range, or column space, of $A$, the answer is generally no. Just think about the case where the rank of $A$ is one, that is $\lambda_1\ne0$ and $\lambda_2 = \dots = \lambda_n = 0$. Then
$$
R(\Lambda) = \{c\in \mathbb{R}^n : c=(x, 0, 0,\dots,0)^T, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$
while
$$
R(A) = \{x q_1 : x \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$
where $q_1$ is the first column of $Q$.
In general you can only say that $R(\Lambda)$ and $R(A)$ have the same dimension, but they may span different subspaces of $R^n$.
